# External USB mouse not being detected by Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, usb, mouse, 17.04

I was given this mouse. I would prefer not having to buy one since I like using gifts.

The brand is named "Spectra", model is PJT-DMS811.

`/var/log/syslog` output is the following:

```
Oct  5 00:29:24 laptophostname kernel: [19823.328794] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
Oct  5 00:29:24 laptophostname kernel: [19823.461441] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19823.697428] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19823.924761] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19824.017909] hpet1: lost 372 rtc interrupts
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19824.057452] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19824.293422] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19824.520729] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
Oct  5 00:29:25 laptophostname kernel: [19824.522067] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19824.730052] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19824.936705] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 44, error -71
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19825.056583] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19825.057578] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19825.265707] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19825.472639] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 45, error -71
Oct  5 00:29:26 laptophostname kernel: [19825.472769] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

After disconnecting all usb devices except for the mouse, lsusb does not detect it. xsetpointer doesn't give anything.

```
(py3.6) ➜  ~ lsusb                        
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2232:1024 Silicon Motion 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(py3.6) ➜  ~ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
11: "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"  [XExtensionPointer]
```

I tried with:

```
(py3.6) ➜  ~ egrep "Name|Handlers" /proc/bus/input/devices | egrep -B1 'Handlers.*mouse'
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5
```

But that information also shows that the mouse isn't detected.

Apparently although the mouse is named Spectra, the maker is Jetion (thus the PJT I think means something like Product Jetion).The product page [shows no real useful information.](http://www.pc210.com/products/product_view.aspx?proid=452) It is a Chinese company and I haven't been able to find anything about drivers.

It worked on Windows and on Mac OS X

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, please unplug all USB devices from your PC, unplug machine so it totally disconnected from power. If it's a laptop also remove the battery.

Now wait a minute or two, then connect everything back to it state, and try use the mouse again.

Source: https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error

Comment: My laptop's battery hasn't worked for a couple of years, so this isn't really a thing. (What I mean is that I have no battery).

Comment: I attempted as much as I could related to this solution but it did nothing. Still thanks for trying.